# Don't show iPhone keyboard for a particular textbox in web page?

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications

Is there any setting using which the iPhone keyboard won't appear for a particular textbox in web page? May be some css kind of setting?

Comment: Sorry for closing this. Despite being much older, the newer (2011) question has attracted better quality answers.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you just make the input field as **readonly="true"**/ readonly mode so that keyboard wont appear!!

Comment: I just tried this, it worked for me!

I'm using the jqueryui datepicker and didn't want the keyboard to pop up. This did the trick.

Comment: this will not show cursor, and users wont be able to see where they are. any solutions for that?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the text box to be editable for any other browser other than the iPhone?  If not, have you attempted to disable the text box?  I haven't tried this, nor can I recall seeing a disabled text box on a site with my iPhone; however, it may do it.

*If disabling the text box works*, but you still only want to restrict it to the iPhone, you'll need to look at the User Agent for the iPhone.  You can determine this through server side code or through JavaScript's `navigator.userAgent`.

To save a bit more time for you as well, the iPhone's user agent is as follows:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3B48b Safari/419.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that readonly="true" isn't required.

`<input type="text" readonly>` is enough.

- [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)
- [StackOverflow Answer 30 May 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172911/what-is-the-difference-between-readonly-true-readonly-readonly)
- [HTML Living
  Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-readonly-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

If you want hide keyboard for iphone/ipad/ipod users you must identify this useragents. I recomend http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ to find different versions of these devices and then printing `readonly="true" disabled="disabled"` on inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to truly disable the keyboard just like you cannot truly disable the keyboard when you browse a webpage via a PC or Mac.  One trick would be to add JavaScript to intercept the OnKeyPress (or OnKeyDown) event to intercept the key stroke and cancel it based on the User Agent.  I haven't tried it against the iPhone specifically but it has worked for other applications when I want to restrict the type of input on an enabled text box (i.e. canceling alpha characters in a phone number field).  Since the "OnKey" events are still valid on the iPhone (as determined by sites with autocomplete like Google), the method should work.