# What is the difference between readonly="true" & readonly="readonly"?

Tags: html

What is the difference between:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" readonly="true" />
```

and:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" readonly="readonly" />
```

When i set `readonly` to `true` it works somewhat different from `readonly='readonly'`. W3C standard says `readonly` should be `'readonly'` & not `'true'`. Why most of the browsers allow `readonly='true'` which has somewhat different functionality than `readonly='readonly'`?

Comment: What markup DOCTYPE, DTD, and what browser mode?

Comment: A more global answer for your specific question is that browsers are made to be compatible with all sorts of loose (and sometimes terrible) coding.  Figuring out the strictest coding that will work with all browsers is a virtue, because kludges will only work until browser developers get fed up with them :)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Giving an element the attribute `readonly` will give that element the readonly status. It doesn't matter what value you put after it or if you put any value after it, it will still see it as readonly. Putting `readonly="false"` won't work.

Suggested is to use the W3C standard, which is `readonly="readonly"`.

Comment: Putting `readonly="false"` won't work in the sense that it won't do the expected thing. It will "work" (have an effect) in the sense that it will make the element readonly (in current browsers, even if it's invalid according to the spec).

Comment: Just to add to that in case it's not clear, to set it to read/write again remove the `readonly` attribute completely

Answer (score 59):

### This is a property setting rather than a valued attribute

These *property settings* are values per see and don't need any assignments to them. When they are present, an element has this boolean property set to `true`, when they're absent they're `false`.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

It's actually browsers that are liberal toward value assignment to them. If you assign any value to them it will simply get ignored. Browsers will only see the presence of a particular property and ignore the value you're trying to assign to them.

This is of course good, because some frameworks don't have the ability to add such properties without providing their value along with them. Asp.net MVC Html helpers are one of them. jQuery used to be the same until version 1.6 where they added the concept of properties.

There are of course some implications that are related to XHTML as well, because attributes in XML need values in order to be well formed. But that's a different story. Hence browsers have to ignore value assignments.

Anyway. **Never mind the value you're assigning to them** as long as the name is correctly spelled so it will be detected by browsers. But for readability and maintainability it's better to assign meaningful values to them like:

```
readonly="true" <-- arguably best human readable
readonly="readonly"
```

as opposed to

```
readonly="johndoe"
readonly="01/01/2000"
```

that may confuse future developers maintaining your code and may interfere with future specification that may define more strict rules to such property settings.

Comment: -1 because the *"arguably best choice to use"* is invalid in both HTML 4.01 and HTML5.

Comment: @Stijn: rephrased that part... So you can remove the downvote if you wish to.

Answer (score 41):

`readonly="true"` is **invalid HTML5**, `readonly="readonly"` is valid.

**HTML5 spec**:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-readonly :

> The readonly attribute is a boolean attribute

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

**Conclusion**:

The following are **valid, equivalent and true**:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" readonly="" />
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" readonly="ReAdOnLy" />
```

The following are **invalid**:

```
<input type="text" readonly="0" />
<input type="text" readonly="1" />
<input type="text" readonly="false" />
<input type="text" readonly="true" />
```

The absence of the attribute is the only valid syntax for **false**:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

**Recommendation**

If you care about writing valid XHTML, use `readonly="readonly"`, since `<input readonly>` is invalid and other alternatives are less readable. Else, just use `<input readonly>` as it is shorter.

Comment: +1, but note that the same counts for HTML 4.01 according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2).

Answer (score 20):

`readonly="readonly"` is **xhtml** syntax. In xhtml boolean attributes are written this way. In xhtml 'attribute minimization' (`<input type="checkbox" checked>`) isn't allowed, so this is the valid way to include boolean attributes in xhtml. See [this page](http://www1.w3schools.com/xhtml/xhtml_syntax.asp) for more.information.

If your [document type](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) is xhtml transitional or strict and you want to validate it, use `readonly="readonly` otherwise `readonly` is sufficient.

Comment: *... so this is the **well formed** way to include boolean attributes in XHTML.*

Comment: @Robert: yep, that the terminology.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how they're functionally different. My current batch of OS X browsers don't show any difference.

I would assume they are all functionally the same due to legacy HTML attribute handling. Back in the day, any flag (Boolean) attribute need only be present, sans value, eg

```
<input readonly>
<option selected>
```

When XHTML came along, this syntax wasn't valid and values were required. Whilst the W3 specified using the attribute name as the value, I'm guessing most browser vendors decided to simply check for attribute existence.

Comment: This has nothing to do with XML being valid, but rather **well formed**. Validity is related to correct naming and valuing of attributes, their nesting etc. Validity has to do with **schema**.

Comment: @Robert I'm referring to XML **syntax** though. Valid XML attribute syntax is `attribute_name="value"`

Comment: @Phil: No that's a **well formed** attribute. A valid attribute is a `int_attribute="1"` or `bool_attribute="false"`... They're of course well formed as well.

Comment: @Robert I'm not talking about validating documents. Perhaps I should use the word "legal" in place of "valid" or any other word that defines the accepted or correct use of characters (ie, syntax)

Comment: @Phil. Well formed XML document is one that passes XML formatting validation (ie. single root element, closing element tags **and** attributes have values (any) assigned to them). But valid XML document is one that is valid against some schema (ie. certain attributes must have correct value type assigned to them, or certain elements can only be nested in particular elements etc.) In your case you're talking about well formed XML attributes (so they have some value assigned to them).

Comment: @Robert Forgetting XML for a minute, would you agree that a piece of computer program code (or markup) may be **syntactically** valid or invalid. If so, then understand that is the definition of **valid** I'm using

Comment: @Phil. I know what you mean. I'm just trying to tell you that this *validness* has a well known name. So why call it any other than *well formed XML*. But never mind. We both know the point of this. And I don't want to argue against otherwise completely fine answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML standards, the use of

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" readonly/>
```

is enough to make the input element readonly. But, XHTML standard says that the usage listed above is invalid due to `attribute minimization`. You can refer to the links below:

https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.5

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: readonly="readonly"   Important if loading via XHTML or similar XML assumptions.