# prevent mobile default keyboard when focusing an <input> from showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, keyboard

this is how i'm trying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dateIn,#dateOut').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

but the input stills 'launching' iphone's keyboard

ps: i want to do this because i'm using datepicker plugin for date

Answer (score 246, accepted):

By adding the attribute `readonly` (or `readonly="readonly"`) to the input field you should prevent anyone typing anything in it, but still be able to launch a click event on it.

This is also usefull in non-mobile devices as you use a date/time picker

Comment: Hm! thanks! but will be the datepicker able to set the choosen value?

Comment: Yes it will. Readonly is only for the user, not for JavaScript.

Comment: -1 since this isn't a very robust method. The input isn't technically "readonly", and as such things like autotabbing (using tabindex="x") doesn't work with this

Comment: Tabindex seems to work still for me. However I can't use `readonly` because certain widgets doesn't bind the event on `readonly` inputs.

Comment: Probably should mention this alternative `readonly="readonly"` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172911/what-is-the-difference-between-readonly-true-readonly-readonly

Comment: @tehlivi not really an alternative, just another value

Comment: Just a note: readonly is a boolean HTML attribute, meaning the presence of it is indicative of the value. You only need "readonly", not "readonly={true|readonly|etc}"

Comment: what abt cursor?

Comment: @ImdadAli cursor? there is not cursor in mobile devices

Comment: 3 years has passed, 2021 now and the answer still work like a charm. Thank you Rene Pot.

Answer (score 71):

## [inputmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) attribute

```html
<input inputmode='none'>
```

> The `inputmode` global attribute is an enumerated attribute that hints at the type of data that might be entered by the user while editing the element or its contents. It can have the following values:

> **`none`** -
> No virtual keyboard. For when the page implements its own keyboard input control.

---

I am using this successfully (Tested on *Chrome/Android*)

[CSS-Tricks: Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About inputmode](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inputmode/)

Comment: This is the correct solution to question, not readonly option

Comment: +1 This is a much better solution, particularly on an ASP.Net web app. Readonly happens to be a control property, so entering in readonly='readonly' causes validation errors.

Comment: So funny how on the [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67908134/10892722) with the same semantic meaning, the same thing happened. The right answer was only added way after the question, and it has way fewer upvotes

Comment: I don't understand why people say this is a better solution than readonly if Safari will still pop up a numeric keyboard. Doesn't sound like a solution to me.

Comment: I don't know about iOS, but in my use case of only needing to support Chrome on Android, this is the answer I was looking for. I was nearly going to implement my own on-screen keyboard to work around it by disabling the Android keyboard entirely (lol).

Comment: I found that this works on iOS Safari - tested with version 15. The docs say that iOS Safari has supported this as of version 12.2 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Comment: Testing in Chrome 114.0.5735.57 in Android 11, this isn't working unfortunately. Edit, doesn't work for `type="number"`, works for `type="text"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched off the whole internet and tried so many things, but this did the trick!

Comment: This still works on Android 13 on every browser I tested it on. Perfect for a scanner web app where you still need to be able to enter data without the keyboard popping up.

Answer (score 12):

You can add a callback function to your DatePicker to tell it to blur the input field before showing the DatePicker.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(){$('input').blur();}
});
```

Note: The iOS keyboard will appear for a fraction of a second and then hide.

Comment: thanks, this works for android, too. For android it even doesn't appear

Comment: Not working for me in android.. Keyboard still pops up

Answer (score 4):

Below code works for me:

```
<input id="myDatePicker" class="readonlyjm"/>


$('#myDatePicker').datepicker({
/* options */
});

$('.readonlyjm').on('focus',function(){
$(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I asked a similar question here and got a fantastic answer - use the iPhone native datepicker - it's great.

[How to turn off iPhone keypad for a specified input field on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812083/how-to-turn-off-iphone-keypad-for-a-specified-input-field-on-web-page)

Synopsis / pseudo-code:

```
if small screen mobile device 

  set field type to "date" - e.g. document.getElementById('my_field').type = "date";
  // input fields of type "date" invoke the iPhone datepicker.

else

  init datepicker - e.g. $("#my_field").datepicker();
```

The reason for dynamically setting the field type to "date" is that Opera will pop up its own native datepicker otherwise, and I'm assuming you want to show the datepicker consistently on desktop browsers.

Comment: The problem is the avaliable or unavaliable dates are already setted with the datepicer... late thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment on the top comment, I'm forced to submit an "answer."

The problem with the selected answer is that setting the field to readonly takes the field out of the tab order on the iPhone.  So if you like entering forms by hitting "next", you'll skip right over the field.

Comment: It makes sense, readonly won't let user change value (only javascript) so i guess is natural taht it skips it

Comment: However, on the desktop browsers I've tested - including Safari/mac - tabbing takes you to the readonly field.

Comment: @JohnVance Is this true even if the tab-index attribute is set? Or would that override the effect? (I'm asking because I don't have an iPhone, but would appreciate the knowledge)

Comment: @FernandoSilva I've tested this on iPhone Safari, with tab-index you'll still skip the field.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to solve this as per my opinion is Using "ignoreReadonly".

First make the input field readonly then add ignoreReadonly:true.
This will make sure that even if the text field is readonly , popup will show.

```
$('#txtStartDate').datetimepicker({
            locale: "da",
            format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
            ignoreReadonly: true
        });
        $('#txtEndDate').datetimepicker({
            locale: "da",
            useCurrent: false,
            format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
            ignoreReadonly: true
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution (similar to John Vance's answer):

First go here and get a function to detect mobile browsers.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

They have a lot of different ways to detect if you are on mobile, so find one that works with what you are using.

Your HTML page (pseudo code):

```
If Mobile Then
    <input id="selling-date" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" max="2999-12-31" min="2010-01-01" value="2015-01-01" />
else
    <input id="selling-date" type="text" class="date-picker" readonly="readonly" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" max="2999-12-31" min="2010-01-01" value="2015-01-01" />
```

JQuery:

```
$( ".date-picker" ).each(function() {
    var min = $( this ).attr("min");
    var max = $( this ).attr("max");
    $( this ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",  
        minDate: min,  
        maxDate: max  
    });
});
```

This way you can still use native date selectors in mobile while still setting the min and max dates either way.

The field for non mobile should be read only because if a mobile browser like chrome for ios "requests desktop version" then they can get around the mobile check and you still want to prevent the keyboard from showing up.

However if the field is read only it could look to a user like they cant change the field. You could fix this by changing the CSS to make it look like it isn't read only (ie change border-color to black) but unless you are changing the CSS for all input tags you will find it hard to keep the look consistent across browsers.

To get arround that I just add a calendar image button to the date picker.  Just change your JQuery code a bit:

```
$( ".date-picker" ).each(function() {
    var min = $( this ).attr("min");
    var max = $( this ).attr("max");
    $( this ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",  
        minDate: min,  
        maxDate: max,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date"
    });
});
```

Note: you will have to find a suitable image.

Answer (score -1):

I have a little generic "no keyboard" script - works for me with Android and iPhone:

```
  $('.readonlyJim').on('focus', function () {
      $(this).trigger('blur')
  })
```

Simply attach add class `readonlyJim` to the input tag and voila.

(*Sorry too much StarTrek here)