# How can we block Android default keyboard for a Particular input Box an webview Page

Tags: javascript, android, html, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a Webview Page contains *HTML5* and *javascript*. For a particular Input Textbox I don't want the Android Default keyboard to appear. ***How to achieve that?***

I know using `webview` is not good for this kind of app but I have to use for my App, please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want a specific input like numbers or email keyboard, then maybe this page can help:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-html5-input-types-to-enhance-the-mobile-browsing-experience

posibilities:

```
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="url" name="url">
<input type="tel" name="tel">
<input type="number" name="number">
<input type="date" name="date">
<input type="time" name="time">
<input type="datetime" name="datetime">
<input type="month" name="month">
```

If you want to hide it completely you can look at this post:

[HTML Mobile -forcing the soft keyboard to hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940287/html-mobile-forcing-the-soft-keyboard-to-hide)