# How to hide soft keyboard using jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have text button:

```
<input type="text" class="field" id="something" name="something" placeholder="text" autofocus   />
```

And i would like to remove `android` soft keyboard and stay in this field (stay in focus). But i need to do that only for this field not for entire document. Is it possible to do that using `jQuery`?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes but then you would need to make the field `readonly`.
But this ofcourse means you can't edit it unless you make other UI to manipulate the field value.

What is the goal of the field?

You can for example use `blur()` to remove focus, and remember in JS what field you had your focus on to do other stuff. But you will still remove the focus.

Also there are more tricks but this will require blur, focusing other fields or making your field uneditable by soft-keyboard.

[How can I hide the Android keyboard using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript)

[HTML Mobile -forcing the soft keyboard to hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940287/html-mobile-forcing-the-soft-keyboard-to-hide)

Comment: When PHP returns error exception i need to be able to scan another value but i need to control screen size (hide soft keyboard)

Comment: Well now you know how to hide they keyboard, choose the trick that works for you.