# How to hide the keyboard when tapping a tabulator cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I am not a mobile developer so please bear with me.
I have created a tabulator table that clients can use to fill out inspections. Some of these clients are going to be using this on mobile phones. I have two fields that are causing problems. One is a drop down, one has a date picker.

The date picker and the drop down work just fine on the mobile phone/tablet. The issue that's occurring is that the keyboard appears on screen and in certain cases this covers the date picker or drop down.

I don't care if the keyboard flashes up for a minute and disappears at this point. The client knows me and knows I'm not a mobile dev, I can get him to deal with that. I just need the keyboard out the way.

```
        table.on("cellEditing", function(cell){
        if(cell.getField() == 'datePicker'){
              ???
```

This is all I have so far. I am not sure how I get it to hide the keyboard. I have reading online about using blur in a lot of places but I don't think I'm using it correctly as when I try nothing happens. Is there something different about tabulator?

I have tried to use blur like in this answer [HTML Mobile -forcing the soft keyboard to hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940287/html-mobile-forcing-the-soft-keyboard-to-hide) but nothing happens.
I've tried picking the cell directly using things like $('[tabulator-field="datepicker"]') combined with .blur() and that isn't doing anything either.

[ I don't have a mac to connect my phone to to check if these show errors in the console, but they don't trigger errors in my browser console, they just do nothing (which is expected on the computer of course!) ]

Comment: My suggestion might fall quite far off the mark, since you haven't posted the relevant bits of your code, but - have you tried making your dropdowns and datepickers `readonly`?

Comment: Here I thought I'd already tried this but I gave it a go and it worked perfectly on the date picker,  thanks a lot! Still stuck with the drop down. I am not using the inbuilt date picker but I am using the inbuilt drop down. Using tabulators "editable:false" isn't the answer, but here's hoping I find one today.