# Bootstrap datetimepicker don't work with readonly or disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I have a serious problem with bootstrap `datetimepicker`, Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faissal_aboullait/kx0e5wmq/) :

```
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" >   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i open my website in mobile, mobile keyboard triggered when i focus the input field so what i need is that only the `datepicker` show without keyboard. So for that i use `readonly` or `disabled`, but the problem is that when i use one of them the bootstrap `datetimepicker` doesn't work.
http://jsfiddle.net/faissal_aboullait/kx0e5wmq/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent iphone default keyboard when focusing an <input>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610758/prevent-iphone-default-keyboard-when-focusing-an-input)

Comment: No because i need a solution for all mobile cases. android and iphone or others

Comment: The post that you talking about is resolved by puting readonly. My post is that this readonly is a the probleme Look at this please : http://jsfiddle.net/faissal_aboullait/kx0e5wmq/1/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If your are still looking for a solution take a look at the snippet. This is exactly what i suggested in the comment, you just have to call datetimepicker with

```
ignoreReadonly: true
```

That's it.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    ignoreReadonly: true
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use the icon to pick your date not the text field. The text field is read only.

Answer (score 1):

The clause readonly="yes" in put statement is workable,
actually required libraries are not included, that are as following ones

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu  {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: calc(100%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following clause

is workable,
if it is not working it simply means required libraries are not included, that are as following ones

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js">    
</script>
```

Comment: readonly="yes" in input statement is workable with following libraries.

Comment: You've added the same answer twice. can you remove one of them please?  additionally, can you explain why your answer is better than the accepted answer?