# How to simulate an autofocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a webview (Android) for our site.
I put the input in autofocus:

```
<input name="barcode" 
        type="search"
        placeholder="Scan Barcode"
        class="form-control"
        autocomplete="off"
        autofocus
        required>
```

When the page is loaded the input is selected but the keyboard of Android does not open => Perfect

But when I focus on this input the android keyboard opens and I do not want it to open because this input is only used to scan barcodes

**So I would like to "simulate" an autofocus when closing a modal (for example)** rather than a simple focus, how to do?

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("input[name='barcode']").focus();
});
```

**EDIT : More details :**

We use these scannettes to access our intranet site :

https://www.jmprime.co.uk/product_info.php/android-barcode-scanner-with-gun-grip-rugged-handheld-ip67-device-with-1d-barcode-reader-p-238

On the page in question there is only one input, **the goal is to enter the input without opening the android keyboard** in order to scan a bar code (they are then sent to the database)

Comment: You try .click after focus? Like `$("input[name='barcode']").focus().click()`

Comment: I just tried, the keyboard opens anyway

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610758

Comment: @Ivar but if this is read-only, I can not send to give during a scan?

Comment: You do not want the user to enter any data into the input?
Is something else going to automatically populate the input?

Comment: @Rocstar Scanners usually auto-type it into the box. You could try to capture the key-down event and then add it to the box itself with JavaScript. That way it can still be read-only.

Comment: Wait, is the user taking an image of a barcode, and the barcode is auto-typed into the input?

Comment: @Alex I edited my post to add more details

Comment: try my last fiddle. It should work. It works on my Galaxy S8, the keyboard doesn't show up. You just need to see if the barcode gets scanned correctly

Comment: @Sampgun It works ! Thank you very much ! But I can not apply a style to my input, for example rounded edges

Comment: How I can add placeholder on label ?

Comment: You add a span inside the label...It will automatically be overwritten...You just have to restore it if $barcode.val() is empty!

Comment: I updated the fiddle to handle the placeholder https://jsfiddle.net/ubdnvsk0/26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610758/prevent-iphone-default-keyboard-when-focusing-an-input/7610923#7610923), readonly seems to work.
I found it difficult to work directly on the input, so I would still use the trick of the fake input.
With `timeout` set at `1ms` it works like charm. (updated fiddle below)

```
<input id="barcode" name="barcode" type="hidden" placeholder="Scan Barcode" required>

<label for="barcode" class="your-cool-class-to-make-this-look-like-an-input" />
```

With the `for` attribute, when clicked, it will focus the related input.

https://jsfiddle.net/ubdnvsk0/26/

Comment: I look forward to your example

Comment: alas it does not work .. when i click on the input with the id test or on the label, the android keyboard opens

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I used Bootstrap 4 for `modal`and jQuery.

I forgot to why `.focus()` sometimes doesn't execute but I remember by putting it into `setTimeout()` with a time of `0`, it does the trick.

> Just in case you get confused with the code: `() => {}` is similar to
>   `function() {}`, it's an `anonymous function` / `callback`
>
> Arrow functions are a more concise way to write function, introduced
>   in `ES6`.
>
> Arrow functions are anonymous functions, which means you
>   cannot name it. Arrow functions do not bind to `this`, they don't create
>   their own `this`, thus the enclosing `this` is being used.
>
> Reading Material: ['Arrow Functions - developer.mozilla.org'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#barcode").focus();
    }, 0);
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <input id="barcode" name="barcode" type="search" placeholder="Scan Barcode" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus required readonly><br>

  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it's incredible, but I just thought of that and tried in my fiddle.
It seems to work.

Comment: Actually I didn't think about that. I wanted to catch all focuses. I used a timeout to add and remove a readonly attribute. But I catch the "focus" event. Because with your code if the user taps the input, the keyboard opens.

Comment: Just add `readonly` parameter into your input. Still focuses. I edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Saying that *"() => {} is the same as  function() {}"* is quite inaccurate. jQuery is almost always better used (for consistency reasons, and the strong `this` binding) with `function`