# Prevent invoking the softkeyboard after tapping a VuetifyJS combobox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vuetify.js, soft-keyboard

I need to use a [VuetifyJS combobox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox) on mobile. As soon as the combobox field gets a tap it invokes the softkeyboard. How to prevent the triggering of the softkeyboard? 
CodePen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxVEea

HTML:

```
  <v-combobox
  v-model="select
  :items="items"
  label="Select an item"
  ></v-combobox>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      select: 'Programming',
      items: [
        'Programming',
        'Design',
        'Vue',
        'Vuetify'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a [`v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) instead? It probably does exactly what you want out of the box. Here's a demo replacing `v-combo` with `v-select` in your Codepen: https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bxwdJj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Vuetify Guide: Combobox API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#api), there is one prop=**type**, which **Sets input type** (if you open the browser inspector, you will see how Vuetify constructs the combobox), and its default value is 'text'. That is why the softkey board auto-pops up when tap it.

One quick solution, set it to **button**. (But the potential risk is the user can't change the value manually anymore. Especially you'd like implement one searchable combobox)

Check below demo (or [open the codepen in your mobile](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJBeOy)):

**Edit:** align input text to left by CSS Specificity (please look into the CSS part in below demo).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      select: 'Programming',
      items: [
        'Programming',
        'Design',
        'Vue',
        'Vuetify'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-menu input[type=button][role=combobox] {
  text-align: left;
}

.v-select__slot > input[type=button][role=combobox] { 
  /*text-align: left;   this one works also, you can open browser inspector, then build your own */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-combobox v-model="select" :items="items" label="Select a favorite activity or create a new one" type="button"></v-combobox>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-combobox v-model="select" :items="items" chips label="I use chips" type="button"></v-combobox>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-combobox v-model="select" :items="items" chips label="I use a scoped slot" type="button">
            <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
              <v-chip
                :selected="data.selected"
                :disabled="data.disabled"
                :key="JSON.stringify(data.item)"
                class="v-chip--select-multi "
                @input="data.parent.selectItem(data.item)"
                type="button"
              >
                <v-avatar class="accent white--text">
                  {{ data.item.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() }}
                </v-avatar>
                {{ data.item }}
              </v-chip>
            </template>
          </v-combobox>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-combobox v-model="select" chips label="I'm readonly" readonly></v-combobox>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great but the text is centered now and not left aligned. This didn't work: `<v-combobox  class="text-xs-left ` Any ideas how to fix  it?

Comment: @Tom, check the updated answer, it should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610758/prevent-iphone-default-keyboard-when-focusing-an-input) using `readonly="true"` solve the issue, I found [a codePen](https://codepen.io/agorilla/pen/FJIic) with more advanced features to try and test the concept. Combobox have a readOnly parameter and could probably be opened by some JS... but !

If you need a combobox without the need for user input, why not use [the selects by the same library](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-light) ? With the proper parameters it render just like a combobox.