# What is the correct readonly attribute syntax for input text elements?

Tags: html, forms, readonly, input-field

As Most, I am familiar with the `readonly` attribute for `text input`, But while reading code from other websites (a nasty habit of mine ) I saw more than one implementation for this attribute:

```
<input type="text" value="myvalue" class="class anotherclass" readonly >
```

and

```
<input type="text" value="myvalue" class="class anotherclass" readonly="readonly" >
```

and I have even seen

```
<input type="text" value="myvalue" class="class anotherclass" readonly="true" >
```

.. And I believe I saw even more, but can not recall the exact syntax now..

So, which one is the correct one that I should use?

Comment: possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/… because both are boolean attributes (not flagged), closely related but focuses on implementation statuses instead of standard: [what is the difference between readonly="true" & readonly="readonly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172911/what-is-the-difference-between-readonly-true-readonly-readonly)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.text.html):

> *readonly* = **"readonly"** or **"" (empty string)** or **empty** -
>   Specifies that element represents a control whose value is not meant to be edited.

So basically it's the same.

Comment: Even if it does work, that doesn't mean you should use it. My recommendation is to stick to the standard. Don't introduce errors just because you can.

Comment: @MrLister The standard recommends sticking to the standard, which, even though it's circular, carries more weight :)

Answer (score 80):

**HTML5 spec**:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-readonly :

> The readonly attribute is a boolean attribute

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

**Conclusion**:

The following are **valid, equivalent and true**:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" readonly="" />
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" readonly="ReAdOnLy" />
```

The following are **invalid**:

```
<input type="text" readonly="0" />
<input type="text" readonly="1" />
<input type="text" readonly="false" />
<input type="text" readonly="true" />
```

The absence of the attribute is the only valid syntax for **false**:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

**Recommendation**

If you care about writing valid XHTML, use `readonly="readonly"`, since `<input readonly>` is invalid and other alternatives are less readable. Else, just use `<input readonly>` as it is shorter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what an absolute brain fart the spec is:  by design, you cannot calculate a value for the attribute to toggle it (e.g. - templated HTML on either server - PHP/JSP/ASP - or client - Angular - with true/false in the attribute value).  You must REMOVE the attribute to turn it off.  NOBODY in the committee realized what a foul-up that was???

Comment: @Roboprog haha, true, it is a bit annoying.

Comment: Very well explained. This should've been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

is should be

```
<input type="text" value="myvalue" class="class anotherclass" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: This is only one of the three valid forms. Ciro Santilli's answer is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use simply **readonly**.  That makes it the most semantic and succinct.

Believe it or not,

```
readonly="false"
```

returns true;

To detect in JavaScript if an element is read-only, use this syntax:

```
element.readOnly
```