# How can I make a textbox readonly in this code

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">First Name:</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="span4" id="inputEmail" name="firstname"  value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="hidden" id="inputEmail" name="id" value="<?php echo $get_id;  ?>" placeholder="First Name" required>
```

Comment: What do you want to make readonly? #inputEmail?

Comment: What is the question here? How to make an input field / a textarea readonly is well documented. You just have to take a look at the documentation and you have your answer.

Comment: This question is somewhat [Already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109358/readonly-attribute-syntax-for-input-text)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **readonly** attribute if you want to make a textfield readable only.

**An example:**

```
<input type="text"value="foo"readonly>
```

**From your code**

```
<label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">First Name:</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="span4" id="inputEmail" name="firstname"  value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>" placeholder="First Name"readonly>
<input type="hidden" id="inputEmail" name="id" value="<?php echo $get_id;  ?>" placeholder="First Name" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make inputEmail a readonly field, you can use

```
<label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">First Name:</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="span4" id="inputEmail" name="firstname"  value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>" placeholder="First Name" required readonly>
<input type="hidden" id="inputEmail" name="id" value="<?php echo $get_id;  ?>" placeholder="First Name" required>
```

Note that I've added the readonly at the end of the input tag in line 3.

Comment: No problem. You can close a question by choosing one of the answers and mark it with the 'tick'.