# Stop user from inputing text in input field

Tags: html, css

Is there a `css` or `html` only way to prevent a user from typing in an input field?

I want to dynamically add stuff and remove stuff etc to an input field but I don't want the user to be able to edit it and using the `disable` attribute on the `html` tag prevents me from doing what I want.

Comment: Please provide your current code.

Comment: @YashJain I only didn't include my code since it was just one `input` field :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `readonly` or `disabled` attribute.

The drawback to using `disabled` is that the value of the `disabled` element won't be submitted when the form is.

You'll likely want `readonly`. Which can easily be styled to look like a disabled element.

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = 'Hello World!';
```

```css
[readonly] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `readonly` - read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can just set the input element's `disabled` property to `true`.  That will prevent the user from modifying its contents, but you can do what you like with it by using Javascript to modify its `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

add readonly to it

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello" readonly />
```

Comment: That's *not* the proper way to close input tags -- they are self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm.....

`<input type="text" name="myInput" value="Whatever" readonly="readonly" />`

More here: [What is the correct readonly attribute syntax for input text elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109358/what-is-the-correct-readonly-attribute-syntax-for-input-text-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can fake the disabled effect using CSS.

```
pointer-events:none;
```

You might also want to change colors etc.

CSS is not meant to change the behavior of form elements. It's meant to change their style only. Hiding a text field doesn't mean the text field is no longer there or that the browser won't send its data when you submit the form. All it does is hide it from the user's eyes.

To actually disable your fields, you must use the `disabled` attribute in HTML or the `disabled` DOM property in JavaScript.

OR JQUERY

```
$('#fieldname').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Disable
$('#fieldname').removeAttr('disabled'); //Enable
```

Comment: I could use tab / shift+tab via keyboard and enter text in the input field

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Which one of the methods above did you do this on?

Comment: `pointer events: none.` ha! neat trick but I can tab and then also use space bar to activate checkbox/radio

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Yeah when he mentioned he wanted to do this using css that's the only thing that came to mind. Thanks for bringing that up though :)