# How to add the readonly attribute with JQuery or Javascript (BUT following the W3C standard!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code to add and remove the property `readonly` works (gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery)):

```
$('#someid').prop('readonly', true);
$('#someid').removeProp('readonly');
```

But the W3C standard recommend to use the readonly attribute without a value (gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172911/what-is-the-difference-between-readonly-true-readonly-readonly)):

We should use: `<input type="text" readonly />`

Instead: `<input type="text" readonly="true or readonly or anything" />`

As `$('#someid').prop('readonly');` doesn't work. What is the code to do it properly?

Comment: You're doing it right!

Comment: I know, it just doesn't follow the W3C recommendation. Maybe is better to ignore it? :/

Comment: By "w3c standard", you aren't referring to w3schools are you?

Comment: `w3schools` is in ***no way*** affliated with W3C (very misleading since the names are very similar). Use whatever material you see on w3schools with caution. IMO, never use w3schools.

Comment: I didn't know @Dom. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Sure thing. From personal experience, using w3schools just lead to more questions rather than answers. In fact, that is the very reason you are here! w3schools contradicts itself!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The proper way to do it is with :

```
$('#someid').prop('readonly', true);
```

or

```
$('#someid').prop('readonly', false);
```

and

```
$('#someid').removeProp('readonly');
```

works fine as well as these are all jQuery methods for the native:

```
document.getElementById('someid').readOnly = true;
```

which sets the `readonly` property appropriately, and if you inspect the element in the console you'll see that the `readonly` attribute is added without a value like it should be according to the W3C specifications.

`readonly` **is** a property, and `prop()` is the method for setting properties.

The specifications for HTML5 says:

> readonly = "readonly" or "" (empty string) or empty
>   Specifies that element represents a control whose value is not meant to be edited.

this means the following is valid:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" readonly="" />
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: With ´$('#someid').prop('readonly', true);´, the console shows that the attribute has been set to `readonly=""`

Comment: And that is totally valid according to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html).

Comment: Typo - needs a capital o: document.getElementById('someid').readOnly = true;

Comment: @Jonathan - yes it does, the native property requires camelcase, thank you !