# Disabling BooleanField's change in django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a BooleanField in my form which I want to be only True. Any ideas how to easily achieve this? Is there an attribute to prevent changing of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using widget attributes.

**Code:**

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ReadonlyBoolField = forms.BooleanField(initial = True)
    ReadonlyBoolField.widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

**Testing:**

```
>>>f = MyForm()
>>>str(f)
'<tr><th><label for="id_ReadonlyBoolField">Readonlyboolfield:</label></th><td><input readonly="True" type="checkbox" name="ReadonlyBoolField" id="id_ReadonlyBoolField" /></td></tr>'
```

**Links:**

- [HTML readonly attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_readonly.asp)
- [Widget.attrs documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)
- [Will readonly="True" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172911/what-is-the-difference-between-readonly-true-readonly-readonly)

Comment: I solved it by creating a ReadOnlyBoolField with title="[Not editable]"