# How do I set an input field to read only with beautiful soup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

How do I set an input element to read only with beautiful soup? 
my element looks like this:

```
<input id="province" value="BC" />
```

I know you can create the new attribute in the tag like you would create a new key for a dictionary but this isn't working:

```
soup.find(id="province")["readonly"]
```

**Solution**

```
soup.find(id="province")["readonly"] = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the tag, then add the `readonly` attribute with a value of `readonly` (or any other value, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172911/what-is-the-difference-between-readonly-true-readonly-readonly)).

It should look something like this:

```
tag = soup.find(id="province")
tag['readonly'] = 'readonly'
```

If you want to add the `readonly` attribute to all of the elements with that id, use this:

```
tags = soup.find_all(id="province")
for tag in tags:
    tag['readonly'] = 'readonly'
```