# Whats the best way to conditionally add readOnly in React?

Tags: reactjs

In React given a prop that provides true/false how would one conditionally add `readOnly` to an input field in JSX?

So if I had `this.props.boolean` whats a terse option for adding readOnly when this.props.boolean == false readOnly isn't attached, when this.props.boolean == true readOnly is attached.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<input readOnly={this.props.boolean} />
```

Comment: This won't work as the value for the readonly attribute has to be "readonly" and not true or false. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172968/9269688)

Comment: This is simple yet effective. No need to write complex if else conditions.

Comment: seems like the upper case `o` changes everything!

Answer (score 4):

This is ugly but it works:

```
{props.readonly ?
    <input placeholder="Can't edit here" readOnly />
    :
    <input placeholder="edit here..."/>
}
```

Make the two controls custom to avoid duplicating as much as possible...

Comment: I find it interesting and a little annoying that people mark this down without comment when the accepted answer is incorrect.